# how do you create a data frame from an existing data frame with summary

Tags: r

I am trying to create to separate data frames what will include Avg, Max and 95th percentile fo the data by Hostname.

1. for the Cpubusy and 2. for the UsedPercentMemory

The data frame would look something like this:

```
Hostname   Avg   Max 95th Percentile
Web01      10     90    92
Web02      5      80    75

dput(d)



structure(list(Hostname = structure(c(8L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("db01", "db02", "farm01", "farm02", 
"tom01", "tom02", "tom03", "web01", "web03"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(6L, 10L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("10/5/2015 1:15", "10/5/2015 1:30", "10/5/2015 2:15", 
    "10/5/2015 4:30", "10/5/2015 8:30", "10/5/2015 8:45", "10/6/2015 8:15", 
    "10/6/2015 8:30", "9/11/2015 5:00", "9/11/2015 6:00"), class = "factor"), 
    Cpubusy = c(31L, 20L, 30L, 20L, 18L, 20L, 41L, 21L, 29L, 
    24L), UsedPercentMemory = c(99L, 98L, 95L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 
    99L, 98L, 63L, 99L)), .Names = c("Hostname", "Date", "Cpubusy", 
"UsedPercentMemory"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Is there an easy way to do this in r, I am trying to avoid loops.

I tried this:

```
dd %>% group_by(Hostname) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean, max))
```

I cannot figure out 95th percentile.

Comment: Yes, and there are countless answers showing how to aggregate data ...

Comment: You have to specify the columns to get the max, mean,  In the example, there are 3 other columns, one of which is factor

Comment: @akrun, I want to be able to pass a variable (for the column that I'll need the summary for).

Comment: In that case `summarise_`

Comment: @akrun, I'm trying something like this: ddply(dd,.(Hostname),numcolwise(mean,na.rm = TRUE)), but I need mean, max and quantile for Cpubusy colunm for each Hostname, any ideas how would do this. Given Cpubusy is in a variable like m<-c("Cpubusy"), there is a reason why I have to use m

Comment: `dd %>% group_by(Hostname) %>% summarise_(Mean = interp(~mean(var, na.rm=TRUE), var=as.name(m)), Max=interp(~max(var, na.rm=TRUE), var=as.name(m)), Quantile= interp(~quantile(var, prob=0.95), var=as.name(m)))`

Comment: @akrun Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: I thought you were using `library(dplyr)` (from the code in your post), also need `library(lazyeval)`

Comment: @akrun, can you post this as an answer, that worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the efficient way

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
dd %>% 
   group_by(Hostname) %>% 
   summarise_(Mean = interp(~mean(var, na.rm=TRUE), var=as.name(m)), 
              Max=interp(~max(var, na.rm=TRUE), var=as.name(m)), 
              Quantile= interp(~quantile(var, prob=0.95), var=as.name(m)))
```